# mongodb pull document from array in an embedded document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document

```
firm    {
    "_id" : 0,
    "users" : [
        { 
            "draft_items" : [
                {
                    "pkg" : "10",
                    "id" : 1
                },
                {
                    "pkg" : "10",
                    "id" : 2
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to pull the element from draft items where `id` is `2`

Here is the expected result:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "users" : [
        { 
            "draft_items" : [
                {
                    "pkg" : "10",
                    "id" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I followed this:[MongoDB pull element from array two levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579703/mondb-pull-element-from-array-two-levels-deep) and tried

```
db.firm.update( { 'users.draft_items.id' : 2 },{ $pull: { "users.$.draft_items": {"id":2} } } )
```

But it did not work!

Comment: Does mongo not find the documents or does mongo not pull the elements out of the array? What does mongo return if you try to find the documents with `db.firm.find( { 'users.draft_items.id' : 2 } )`?

Comment: Your `update` command worked fine when I tried it.

Comment: Its finds but not pulling