# Mongo: Removing elements from array inside an array

Tags: list, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following mongo structure:

```
{
"_id": 123,
"rooms": [
    {
        "room_code": 456,
        "img": [
            {
                "link": "blah",
                "title": "Title"
            },
            {
                "link": "blah2",
                "title": "Title2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "room_code": 789,
        "img": [
            {
                "link": "blah",
                "title": "Title"
            },
            {
                "link": "blah3",
                "title": "Title3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Now,  I want to remove those elements from "rooms.img" key where `"link":"blah"`. Like this:

```
{
"_id": 123,
"rooms": [
    {
        "room_code": 456,
        "img": [
            {
                "link": "blah2",
                "title": "Title2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "room_code": 789,
        "img": [
            {
                "link": "blah3",
                "title": "Title3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I tried using,

```
db.collections.update({"_id":123},{$pull: { 'rooms':{'img': { 'l': 'blah' } }}})

db.collections.update({"_id":123},{$pull: { 'room_info.img': { 'l': 'blah' } }})
```

But neither of them is working. How to remove an element from a list("img") which is part of another list ("rooms")? Please advise.

Comment: `$elemMatch` might help here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the projection opperator [Doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

In addition look at my old post : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637772/mongodb-pull-array-2-level/21639858#21639858)