# MongoDB Remove items from an Array of embedded documents

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following data structure:

```
{ 
_id: 599cfc236ed0d81c98007f66
site: 'abc'
timepoints [
    { timepoint: 0
      testSites: [{testSite: 'abc', address: '123'},
                  {testSite: 'mno', address: '789'}],
    },
    { timepoint: 2
      testSites: [{testSite: 'abc', address: '123'}],
    },
    { timepoint: 4
      testSites: [{testSite: 'mno', address: '789'}],
    },
  ]
}
```

I have read through the MongoDB update operator for [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull), but it does not have an example of pulling a element from an array of an embedded/embedded document and I can't figure it out:

I would like to pull all elements whose **site** = 'abc' and whose **testSite** = 'abc', thus the result would be:

```
{ 
_id: 599cfc236ed0d81c98007f66
site: 'abc'
timepoints [
    { timepoint: 0
      testSites: [{testSite: 'mno', address: '789'}],
    },
    { timepoint: 2
      testSites: [],
    },
    { timepoint: 4
      testSites: [{testSite: 'mno', address: '789'}],
    },
  ]
}
```

I tried the following command, but it pulls all the timepoints documents and not the embedded documents within testSites:

```
$db->collection1->update(
         ['site' => 'abc'],
         ['$pull' => ['timepoints' => ['testSites' => ['$elemMatch' => ['testSite' => 'abc']]]]],
         ['multi' => true]);
```

**UPDATE:**
I agree this is a duplicate question with an answer.  I was just able to find the following:

[MongoDB $pull array 2 level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637772/mongodb-pull-array-2-level)

So the command does pull the lower level element, but only from timepoint 0:

```
db.collection1.update({'site': 'abc', 
                       'timepoints.testSites.testSite': 'abc'},
                      {'$pull': {'timepoints.$.testSites': {'testSite': 'abc'}}},
                      {'multi': true}
                     );
```

Why is the second occurrence in timepoint 2 not pulled?

Comment: `->update([ 'site' => 'abc' , 'timepoints.timepoint' => 0 ],[ '$pull' => [ 'timepoints.$.testsites' => [ 'testSite' => 'abc' ] ] ])`. That's the general correction as pointed out ( not actually in the accepted answer ) in the responses to the linked duplicate. Also note that it is not possibly at this present time to update "multiple array elements" in a single request. ( other linked duplicate )

Comment: Thank you, you just answered my question to "multiple array elements" in a single request.  So what is my best option to pull all testSite = 'abc' from timepoints.

Comment: I actually answered both questions when you look carefully.

Comment: Thanks, instead of a single request I went ahead and built a cursor and iterated over each timepoint and if it had assaySites I iterated over each assaySite.  If it matched my requirement I unset the index and check if the assaySites was emtpy and unset the assaySites array.