# MongoDB / NPM mongojs package / Changes one level deep array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

How can I pull from the following MongoDB document all `null` values in, so that there are no more `null` values in the groups array? I want to do it in NodeJS.

(In my real document I have more embedded documents in the tables array with the same structure)

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a4267b9734d1d5b99268cbe"
    },
    "department": "waeldlerStubeKristallStube",
    "tables": [
        {
            "arrayIndex": 0,
            "department": "waeldlerStubeKristallStube",
            "number": "50",
            "topValue": "139",
            "leftValue": "455",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",
            "isBesetzt": "false",
            "placeholder": "true",
            "border": "solid 3px #f3efe4",
            "width": "40",
            "height": "35",
            "groups": [
            null,
                {
                    "nameValue": "Hunziker, Iveta",
                    "zimmernummerValue": "460",
                    "anreiseValue": "16.02.2018",
                    "abreiseValue": "25.02.2018",
                    "personenAnzahlValue": "2/1",
                    "notiz2Value": "2*50 Euro Spa Taler",
                    "notiz1Value": "2 Erw neu + 1 Baby geänderte reservierung neues Datum",
                    "traceValue": "-",
                    "bemerkungValue": "-"
                },
            null
            ]
        }
]
}
```

It seems to me that I need to update the document, query all the groups with the value null, which is in the tables array and pull the null with

```js
tables.$.groups
```

including a positional operator. I had also a look at the following post: [MongoDB pull element from array two levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579703/mongodb-pull-element-from-array-two-levels-deep)
and came up with this try:

```js
db.hubertusTables.update({"tables.groups": null},{ $pull: { "tables.$.groups": null} }, { multi: true});
```

My try does not work. I get the following response:

```js
{"n":2,"nModified":0,"opTime":{"ts":"6526469489381343253","t":4},"electionId":"7fffffff0000000000000004","ok":1}
```

Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: Why? And you might want to `find` not to `update` ...

Comment: When I use find I get the following response: `{ MongoError: Unsupported projection option: $pull: { tables.$.groups: null }`

Comment: Whats your usecase? What are you trying to do with all of this?

Comment: I want to `$pull` from the above given MongoDB document all null values, so that there are no more `null` values in the groups array? This should be done in NodeJS

Comment: Now i get you. `update({"tables.groups": null}` that only updates groups were the groups actually dont exist, so you might do `update({}` to apply it to all documents

Comment: Sorry, my question was not formulated well I think. If I make your suggested changes I get the following response: `{ MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: tables.$.groups`

Comment: Oh right and `updateMany` instead of `update`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using monogjs package, there is no `updateMany`. Probably I need to do some changes.

Comment: Without changing from mongojs I found a solution: I queried the collection with `db.collection.find()`, then I saved the documents in an temporary array via a callback. I made the changes in the array, removed the documents from the collection `db.collection.remove()` and then I saved the array to the collection as new documents `db.collection.save(tablesTemp3[0])`

Comment: Ok. That sounds more complicated than i thought it would be. However maybe others will have the same problem, so feel free to add an answer to this to help others :)

Comment: Great, I hope it is a good approach to solve the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Without changing from mongojs I found a solution: I queried the collection with `db.collection.find()`, then I saved the documents in a temporary array via a callback. I made the changes in the array, removed the documents from the collection with `db.collection.remove()` and then I saved the array to the collection as new documents `db.collection.save(tablesTemp[0])`